# Shortcode for author page for custom post type (Wordpress)

Tags: wordpress

I am trying to make a website where there is an author page. I want to have a tab where I can put all posts by that author.

So the thing is, I have made tabs, now I want to make a shortcode or anything like this so I put in WordPress and it shows all custom posts by that user in that tab.

Author URL is xyz.com/profile/athr01/.

Here I want the shortcode which will take athr01 which is in URL and show that custom post according to that.

Please let me know if it is possible and if yes then how.

Comment: WordPress supports author pages natively by default. Have you looked at the documentation? https://codex.wordpress.org/Author_Templates

Comment: Thanks for your reply
I tried to find solution on this link but didn't got as I need.
I need to create a shortcode which I want to put in user profile tab. And with that shortcode, I want it take the author name form URL like Author URL is xyz.com/profile/athr01/, So I want that it take only "athr01" and show only his/her posts at that place where I add that shortcode in profile page.
Thanks

Comment: You posted the same question 1 week back right ?

Comment: If you know how to create a shortcode, then the link provided by @JoBatkin includes the needed information - $curauth = (isset($_GET['author_name'])) ? get_user_by('slug', $author_name) : get_userdata(intval($author));, then you have your author object - which only leeds to you making a wp_query to get the post created by that author and make the loop with it.